Injective map from $\mathcal O_L / P$ to $\mathcal O_M / Q$.
Our setup here is that $\mathbb Q \subset L \subset M$ are fields. We have that $P$ is a prime factor of $p\mathcal O_L$ ($p$ is a prime number) and that $Q$ is a prime factor of $P\mathcal O_M$. Im trying to show that there exists an injective map from $\mathcal O_L / P$ into $\mathcal O_M / Q$ (I hope that such a claim is in fact true). I'm puzzled how to construct the map. We do have an inclusion $\mathcal O_L \to \mathcal O_M$ and a projection $\mathcal O_M \to \mathcal O_M / Q$ so if I can show that $P = \mathcal O_L \cap Q$ then that should complete the proof, but I don't even know if $\mathcal O_L \cap Q \subseteq P$ is true?

Let $x\in P$. Then clearly $x\in\mathcal O_L$ and since $Q$ is a factor of $P\mathcal O_M$, we have $P\mathcal O_M\subseteq Q$, so $x\in Q$. Together this means $x\in\mathcal O_L\cap Q$, so we have shown $P\subseteq\mathcal O_L\cap Q$. (This even implies that $P=\mathcal O_L\cap Q$ since $P$ is maximal, but we won't need that.)
In other words, $P$ is contained in the kernel of the map $\mathcal O_L\hookrightarrow\mathcal O_M\twoheadrightarrow\mathcal O_M/Q$ that you described. Therefore, by the universal property of quotients, it factors through a map $\mathcal O_L/P\to\mathcal O_M/Q$.
Finally, proving that this map is injective is easy: $\mathcal O_L$ is a Dedekind domain, so the non-zero prime ideal $P$ is maximal, i.e. $\mathcal O_L/P$ is a field. But all ring morphisms out of fields are injective. (Otherwise the kernel would be a non-trivial ideal.)

@anakElpis Thanks for that. I didn't realize that any ring homomorphism out of a field must be injective (I guess that has to do with the fact that the kernel has to be the entire field or just the zero ideal, so the trivial map).
